# Erro Sequelize: SequelizeDatabaseError

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express.js, sequelize-js

Olá, estou construindo minha aplicação em node e usando banco de dados postgres. Me deparo com o seguinte erro:

```
SequelizeDatabaseError: column \"zipcode\" of relation \"users\" does not exist"
```

Meu model está da seguinte forma:

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

class Addresses extends Model {
    static init(connection) {
        super.init({
            zipcode: DataTypes.STRING,
            street: DataTypes.STRING,
            number: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        }, {
            sequelize: connection,
        })
    }

    static associate(models) {
        this.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'user_id' });
    }
}

module.exports = Addresses;
```

Meu controller está da seguinte forma:

```
const User = require('../models/User');
const Adresses = require('../models/Adresses');

module.exports = {
    async store(req, res) {

        const { user_id } = req.params;
        const { zipcode, street, number } = req.body;

        const user = await User.findByPk(user_id);

        try{

            if(!user) {
                return res.status(400).json({error: 'User not found'})
            }

            const address = await Addresses.create({
                zipcode,
                street,
                number,
                user_id,
            });

            return res.json(address);

        }catch(err) {
            return res.status(400).json({error: 'Algo deu errado: '+err});
        }
    }
};
```

As rotas:

```
const express = require('express');

const UserController = require('./controllers/UserController');
const AddressesController = require('./controllers/AddressesController');

const routes = express.Router();

routes.get('/users', UserController.index);
routes.post('/users', UserController.store);

routes.post('/users/:user_id/adresses', AddressesController.store);

module.exports = routes;
```

E a chamada de cada função para inserção e conexão com o banco:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const dbConfig = require('../config/database');

const User = require('../models/User');
const Addresses = require('../models/Addresses');

const connection = new Sequelize(dbConfig);

User.init(connection);
Addresses.init(connection);

Addresses.associate(connection.models);

module.exports = connection;
```

O banco de dados está configurado certinho pq já rodei as migrations e deu tudo certo. No banco de dados, a tabela **addresses** foi criada da seguinte forma pelo Sequelize:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.addresses
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('addresses_id_seq'::regclass),
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    zipcode character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    street character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "number" integer NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT addresses_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT addresses_user_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
        REFERENCES public.users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.adresses
    OWNER to postgres;
```

Estou tentando fazer o cadastro pelo **Insomnia** na rota **http://localhost:3333/users/1/addresses** passando o seguinte json:

```
{
    "zipcode": "----",
    "street": "-------",
    "number": ---
}
```

Mais o **Insomnia** me retorna esse erro **SequelizeDatabaseError: column "zipcode" of relation "users" does not exist"**, sendo que no meu model, eu fiz a associação.

Podem me ajudar?
Desde já grato...

Comment: Seguinte, o erro é claro: `column zipcode` `users` `does not exist` a minha resposta, vem com uma pergunta, consegue mostrar o que retorna o seu `address`?

Comment: já irei te mandar.

Comment: Seria esse código que vc quer?  

`
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

class Addresses extends Model {
    static init(connection) {
        super.init({
            zipcode: DataTypes.STRING,
            street: DataTypes.STRING,
            number: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        }, {
            sequelize: connection,
        })
    }

    static associate(models) {
        this.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'user_id' });
    }
}

module.exports = Addresses;
`

@JhowBhz

Comment: Não... você poderia debugar a aplicação e vê o que tem no objeto `address`?

Comment: Já encontrei o erro. Quando chamava a minha model chamava da seguinte forma: **const Addresses = require('./models/Adresses)** faltando um **d**. O correto seria **const Addresses = require('./models/Addresses)**. Obrifgado pela ajuda, mais o erro foi de português mesmo.

Comment: Pode fechar a pergunta pra mim por favor?

Comment: :D Resolvido! like it.

Comment: @Cesar4ugusto Sua pergunta está na fila de análise para fechamento, mas você pode removê-la. Leia mais aqui: [O que é melhor, deixar fechar a pergunta ou remover?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1555/100416)